# How to get length of possibly null database field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am attempting to get the length (in characters) of the longest particular field in my database, even in the case of no field values. Sometimes in our database there are no values for any of the .UnitIDs, which throws an error when attempting to use .Max(). Here is my current query:

```
 var unitIDWidth = data.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(x => x == null ? 0 : x.UnitID.Length);
```

I thought this code would work but it still throws this exception:

> 'The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'

I have also tried this:

```
var unitIDWidth = data.Where(x=>x.UnitID != null).Select(x=>x.UnitID.Length).Max();
```

But it also throws an exception.

I need this query to return 0 if all values are null, or the max character count if there are values in that particular field.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the exception for the second linq query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement you are checking if the entire record is null:

```
.Max(x => x == null ? 0 : x.UnitID.Length);
```

while you must be checking if specifically the column `UnitID` is null or not; so try this:

```
.Max(x => x.UnitID == null ? 0 : x.UnitID.Length);
```